# Reading and parsing binary data

Tags: java

I have a file stored in disk and its structure is blocks with records of fixed size. 
Each record consists of two integers and one double (with precision: ##.##). 
I want to read a specific block in memory, find a specific record and store its data in a class Rec instance.

So far I am reading the block like this:

```
public void read(int blockNumber, byte buffer[]) {
    System.arraycopy(data, blockNumber * BLOCK_SIZE,buffer, 0,BLOCK_SIZE);
    // block is stored in buffer
}
```

While I have worked in C with byte handling, I am very confused in java.
If I want to retrieve the 3rd record for example, I know that it starts 
at buffer[2*RECORD_SIZE]. But, how do I retrieve the first int (of size: Integer.SIZE)?
Probably noob question but I am completely stuck..

Comment: What's your approach to reading the data from the file, read it fully to memory? If you are going to do that, why not convert the records into objects while you read?

Comment: I want to read part of the file in memory, do some changes and write it back. The C-equivalent would be a series of memread-memcpy-memwrite. The approach that you propose, how could it be implemented?

Comment: What are memread and memwrite? Do you mean fread?

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant these functions http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.14.html#memcpy for handling bytes.